# PowerShell scripts are disabled to run in my system

Tags: powershell, uac

I was recently watching a YouTube video of Hak5 and one of his videos were of the vulnerability of bypassing UAC and escalation of privileges through a `.ps1` script. You can check the video out [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9GfMfFjhYI).

But when experimenting on my own machine, PowerShell throws an error:

[image]

*Image Source: StanleyUlili*

Scripts are disabled to be run in my PowerShell. I searched on the web but did not find a good solution neither many of them worked.

How can I enable running scripts in PowerShell without running PowerShell as an administrator?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Run  `get-executionpolicy`, what comes back?

Comment: Did you read the link provided in the error message?

Comment: Sorry but this question has been answered all over the internet a million times. Just google your question and you'll find hundreds of articles.